# How to unit test a method that returns Action<AuthenticationOptions>?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I am trying to unit test this method which returns `Action<SomeOptions>`.

```
public class MyOption
{
    public Action<SomeOptions> GetOptions()
    {
        return new Action<SomeOptions>(o =>
            {
                o.Value1 = "abc";
                o.Value2 = "def";
            }
        );
    } 
}
```

I would like to verify in my test that `Value1` is `"abc"` and `Value2` is `"def"`

```
[Test]
public void GetOptions_ReturnsExpectedOptions()
{   
    var option = new MyOption();

    Action<SomeOptions> result = option.GetOptions();

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);

    //I also want to verify that the result has Value1="abc" & Value2 = "def"
}
```

I am not sure how to test that part of code that verifies that the result has `Value1="abc"` & `Value2 = "def"`

Comment: Call the returned action and assign the result and then verify the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Igor commented, you have to invoke the action and check the results of the action. Try this:

```
[Test]
public void GetOptions_ReturnsExpectedOptions()
{
    var option = new MyOption();

    Action<SomeOptions> result = option.GetOptions();

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);


    //Assign SomeOptions and pass into the Action
    var opts = new SomeOptions();
    result(opts);
    Assert.AreEqual("abc", opts.Value1);
    Assert.AreEqual("def", opts.Value2);
}
```